# How to fuse two axis of a n-dimentional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Instead of a n-dimentional array, let's take a 3D array to illustrate my question :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.ones(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)
```

So I have an array of shape (2, 3, 4). I would like to concatenate/fuse the 2nd and 3rd axis together to get an array of the shape (2, 12).

Wrongly, thought I could have done it easily with `np.concatenate` :

```
>>> np.concatenate(arr, axis=1).shape
(3, 8)
```

I found a way to do it by a combination of np.rollaxis and np.concatenate but it is increasingly ugly as the array goes up in dimension:

```
>>> np.rollaxis(np.concatenate(np.rollaxis(arr, 0, 3), axis=0), 0, 2).shape
(2, 12)
```

Is there any simple way to accomplish this? It seems very trivial, so there must exist some function, but I cannot seem to find it.

EDIT : Indeed I could use `np.reshape`, which means to compute the dimensions of the axis first. Is it possible without accessing/computing the shape beforehand?

Comment: .... `Reshape`?

Comment: No, you need to reshape. And it's better because no copy.

Comment: I am searching for an even simpler way. Using reshape would mean to compute the shape of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On recent python versions you can do:

```
anew = a.reshape(*a.shape[:k], -1, *a.shape[k+2:])
```

I recommend against directly assigning to `.shape` since it doesn't work on sufficiently noncontiguous arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you have `n` dimensions in your array and that you want to fuse adjacent axis `i` and `i+1`:

```
shape = a.shape
new_shape = list(shape[:i]) + [-1] + list(shape[i+2:])
a.shape = new_shape
```

Comment: It is definitly more elegant than my rollaxis trick! Thank you. I will accept the answer if nothing interesting shows up :).